# Find out whether current request is a proxy request in firefox?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, xul

I need to automatically perform authorization with a proxy server using an addon.

I also checked out the source of other extensions that do that, and they do it like this:

```
var httpRequestObserver =
{
    observe: function(subject, topic, data)
    {
        if (topic === "http-on-modify-request") {
            var channel = subject.QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIHttpChannel);
            channel.setRequestHeader("Proxy-Authorization", "Basic myauthorizationtoken" , false);
        }
    }
};
```

A request observer adds the authorization header to every outgoing request. That works fine if a regular proxy is set, however in my case i have a proxy pac url where only specific requests are done using the proxy, and others not!

In that case the authorization header which basically includes credentials in the clear is transmitted to every website not accessed via proxy.

Obviously that cannot be, therefore I need to find out whether the current request is a proxy request, and only then set the header.

Or find another way alltogether...

In chrome I did it like this:

```
chrome.webRequest.onAuthRequired.addListener(handleAuthRequest,
  {urls: ["<all_urls>"]}, ["asyncBlocking"]);


function handleAuthRequest(details, callback) {

  if (details.isProxy === true){

    callback({authCredentials: {username: localStorage['login'],
                              password: localStorage['pass']}});
   }
     callback();

}
```

Clearly this is optimal! However I cannot see a nice way in firefox to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turns out that subject has an attribute proxyInfo which is null or set, also proxyInfo has further attributes to examine

Comment: sorry bro its been a long time. the apis probalby got updated several times by now. also chrome has become really picky about allowing proxy modfications in their extensions. there are new guidelines and everything.